# Replace block text in ini file

Tags: regex, powershell

I need replace a block text inside a .ini file.
My script is:

```
$oFile = "$Env:ProgramFiles (x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent\Settings.ini
$oSettings = Get-Content -Path $oFile
$oPattern = '[PATCHMANAGEMENT](.*?)[SITECONCENTRATOR]'
$oTextToReplace = [regex]::match($oSettings , $oPattern).Groups[1].Value
$oNewFile = $oSettings -replace $oTextToReplace.ToString, "][" | out-file -FilePath $Env:ProgramFiles 
(x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent\newSettings.ini
```

But it is not working. Can you help me with this?
Sorry for my weak English.
Greetings!

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Its Work but I need mantain the tags [PATCHMANAGEMENT] and [SITECONCENTRATOR] and replace the text betwen the tags.Can you help me wit this?

Comment: Yes, but isn't the answer below showing how it can be done?

Comment: This is a command:
`$oFile = "$Env:ProgramFiles (x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent\Settings.ini"
$oSettings = Get-Content -Path $oFile -Raw
$oPattern = '\[PATCHMANAGEMENT].*?\[SITECONCENTRATOR]'
$oNewFile = $oSettings -replace '$1$2', "][" | out-file -FilePath "$Env:ProgramFiles (x86)\Advanced Monitoring Agent\
newSettings.ini".`

Result in the new file:
[PATCHMANAGEMENT]
ACTIVATED=1
CURRENTSTATE=0
VERSION=16
[SITECONCENTRATOR]

Comment: I use this command 
$oNewFile = $oSettings -replace $oPattern, '$1$2' | out-file -FilePath "$Env:UserProfile\Desktop\newSettings.ini".
Works fine 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should read the file in as a single variable:

```
$oSettings = Get-Content -Path $oFile -Raw
```

Next, use a DOTALL, or `(?s)` inline modifier at the pattern start, to make `.` match across lines. Also, escape `[` that is outside a character class to make it match a literal `[`, else, it denotes a character class start. Then, enclose the tags you want to keep, not the text in between the tags:

```
$oPattern = '(?s)(\[PATCHMANAGEMENT]).*?(\[SITECONCENTRATOR])'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/76yh1i/1) (just how it works).

The rest is a mere `-replace`:

```
$oNewFile = $oSettings -replace $oPattern, '$1$2' |
  out-file -FilePath "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Advanced Monitoring Agent\newSettings.ini"
```